# How to open XUL window/dialog in a new tab?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

Is it possible to open .xul file containing window or dialog as a new tab? I can open it as a separate window using window.open or window.openDialog, but I would prefer if it were a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [loadOneTab()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/loadOneTab):

```
gBrowser.loadOneTab("chrome://.../window.xul");
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Opening_a_URL_in_a_new_tab

Comment: Great! gBrowser.addTab() perfectly suits my needs.